# SQL query for calculating average on specific groups

Tags: t-sql

I will try to explain my problem with this example table:

[image]

I need to calculate the average of the high and low value to generate the 'mid' value but only if it isn't already in the table.

Group by is a good start to get all the mid values. But how do I avoid overwriting existing mid values? And how do I include them in the view with all the other data?

Comment: Link to image is not enough.  Write out the question.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask] and the accepted answer of ["Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Hy i included more details in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start:

```
select Key_Name, Key_Date, Key_ID1, Key_Type, Value, Key_Module from T
union all /* all isn't strictly necessary though generally faster */    
select
    Key_Name, Key_Date, 'mid' as Key_Type,
    min(Key_ID1) as Key_ID1 -- ??
    avg(Value), -- (max(Value) - min(Value)) / 2.0
    min(Key_Module) as Key_Module
from T
group by Key_Name, Key_Date
having count(case when KeyType = 'mid' then 1 end) = 0
```

It isn't clear what you intended to have happen with the `Key_Module` and `Key_ID1` columns.

Comment: I will take this as solution but to finalize it i needed to "union all" with the full table again. So then I had all the calcualted mid + origin mid + other values

Comment: The words "update" and "view" have specific meanings in a SQL context. It wasn't entirely clear from the question exactly what you were intending to do. I'm glad you figured out how to do a union though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not the below?

```
select KeyType,Avg(Value) from mytable group by KeyType
```